# Submit form using Codeigniter URI Routing not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have to update a site, that i did not create, with a forum. The site is create with codeigniter's last version. 
I'm a newbie in routing uri.

When I submit my form, I have an error "404 The page you requested was not found".
The method add_post() that I want to execute is in the Class Admin_adherent_forum_C. This class is in the controllers/admin_adherent folder.
There's something wrong with the route but I don't know what?

HTML :

```
<form action="<?=base_url('espace-adherent/forum/creer_sujet.html')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="CreateSubjectHeader">
        <p>Nouveau sujet</p><a href=".CreateSubject" id="openButtonSubject">+</a><a id="closeButtonSubject">-</a>
      </div>
      <div id="contentSubject">
        <div class="CreateSubject">
          <div class="CreateSubjectTitle">
            <label>Titre :</label>
            <input type="text" name="sujet" value="" required>
          </div>
          <div class="CreateSubjectContent">
            <label>Texte :</label>
            <textarea name="discussion" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="CreateSubjectCategory">
            <label>Catégorie :</label>
            <select id="selectCategory" class="categorie" name="categorie[]" multiple>
              <option value="1">Entreprise</option>
              <option value="2">Collaborateurs</option>
              <option value="3">Recyclage</option>
              <option value="4">Valorisation</option>
              <option value="5">Aménagement</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="CreateSubjectFooter">
          <img class="FileIcon" src="/img/file_icon.svg" alt="">
          <input id="file" class="FileInput" type="file" name="fichier_sujet" value="">
          <input class="SubmitButton" type="submit" name="publier" value="Publier">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

PHP :

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Admin_adherent_forum_C extends CI_Controller {
   public function add_post()
    {
      my code here...
    }
  }
```

ROUTES :

```
$route['espace-adherent/forum/creer_sujet']= 'admin_adherent/Admin_adherent_forum_C/add_post';
```

Comment: your form action url is not match with routed path

Comment: Thanks for the answer, wrong paste.

I try to match url with routed paths but it's the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form action change URL with this.

```
base_url('espace-adherent/forum/creer_sujet');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, wrong paste.

I try to match url with routed paths but it's the same error.

Comment: what happened ?

Comment: Always the same error "404 The page you requested was not found".

I update my post with the right route. 
$route['espace-adherent/forum/creer_sujet']= 'admin_adherent/Admin_adherent_forum_C/add_post

Comment: Thanks, I try. Now I have a white page and nothing is insert.

Answer (score 0):

In the form action the URL given in

> base_url('espace-adherent/forum/creer_sujet.html')

But the URL configured in the is

> $route['espace-adherent/forum/add_post']=
>   'admin_adherent/Admin_adherent_forum_C/add_post';

Update: Please try to remove `.html` from the form action.

Hope it works. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, wrong paste.

I try to match url with routed paths but it's the same error.

Comment: I update my post with the right route.

$route['espace-adherent/forum/creer_sujet']= 'admin_adherent/Admin_adherent_forum_C/add_post';

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. It comes from the .htaccess rewriting mode. I don't know how and why but it was disabled.